# Out of Memory Error ,set bitmap on TouchImageview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-memory

In my app i am using a Touch imageview to enable zoom and crop option for user.For that first i have converted the image uri to bitmap using this method .

Uri to bitmap

```
   private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 140;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    String imageType = o.outMimeType;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {

        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);

}
public Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) {
    //Log.e(TAG, "Camera Image 3");
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
  Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    //  imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

After that i have Scaled my bitmap using this method

```
   public Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap rotated)
{

    final int maxSize = 300;
    int outWidth;
    int outHeight;
    int inWidth = rotated.getWidth();
    int inHeight = rotated.getHeight();
    if(inWidth > inHeight){
        outWidth = maxSize;
        outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
    } else {
        outHeight = maxSize;
        outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
    }

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotated, outWidth, outHeight, false);


    // imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    // imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

   // mGPUImageView = (GPUImageView) findViewById(R.id.gpuimage);
   // mGPUImageView.setImage(resizedBitmap);
    return resizedBitmap;

}
```

The output of this method that is a resizedBitmap ,I have set this bitmap to imageview like this

```
   touchimageview.setImageBitmap( scaleBitmap(decoded));
```

After doing all these scaling and decoding techniques still i am getting out of memeory error ,How can i solve this issue can anyone help ??

Comment: Did you try to use any of the image libraries like Picasso,  universal image loader etc?

Comment: Yes i am loading sdcard images to a grid layout using UIL ,and the user selected image bitmap was directly used in setImageBitmap method

Comment: Anything wrong with my code ?? can you help ?

Comment: Ex of UIL:
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(imageUrl,         new ImageSize(viewWidth, viewheight),         displayImageLoaderOptions,         new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {             @Override             public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {                 mImageMap.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);             }         });

Try doing this way. While setting image to view, you should use this.

Comment: @jaxon looks everything is fine once try to comment the line fitImageToView(); on TouchIMageView setImageBitmap method and run let me know in case of issue

Comment: @cgr and Sandy : Thank you very much for the replay ,I have tried that code snippet but still i could not resolve the problem

Comment: loadImage() and displayImage() are different APIs for same purpose. Good you could resolve it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load Image to TouchIamgeView using UIL displayImage function.

Try this;

```
ImageLoader imageloader;
 TouchImageView touchImageView = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.);


    imageLoader.displayImage(imageURL,touchImageView);
```

Answer (score -1):

As a quick fix you can try to add this to your Application tag in the Manifest file:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

BUT:

> Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being allocated and why it must be retained.

More information: [Android Dev - Managing app memory](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)